# the paper status was back from "decision in process" to "under review"

Tags: phd

I submitted a paper to Journal of comparative physiology-B. After major revision, two reviewers gave me minor revision (only change one word) and the editor was pleased to consider publication. After re-submission, the status changed from "under review" to "decision in process". However, the status was then back to "under review". What does it mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like

Comment: Not enough information to say. I suggest patience.

Comment: I assume by now you have more details: so what does it mean?

Answer (score 4):

The question presupposes that the behavior of such an editorial system has a meaning. Granting that presupposition, my first guess is that the editor got the reviewers' reports and was about to make a decision ("decision in process") but then noticed that something was unclear in one of the reports and asked the reviewer for a clearer report ("under review").

Comment: But would it be potentially positive or negative? That is the point I suppose.

Comment: Yes, it wold be potentially positive or negative. Obviously, if my guess is right and the editor is asking a reviewer for a clearer reports, the decision would depend on that report.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of a reviewer, it's just a button you press. Sometimes you accidentally press one button, even when you meant another. In your situation, the change it status might now mean anything and it's still under review.